# Rails keep and display model method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I have a model in rails for movies and within this model I have a method that parses JSON and adds each movie from that to a database.

My controller so far has an index to list the movies and it has a create action that triggers the model method that parses the JSON.

```
def create
 @movie = Movie.parse_json
 if @movie
  redirect to root_path
 else
 render new_movie_path
end
```

the parse json method just parses each json element and adds it as a new movie.

My main predicament is I think I'm doing things a little wrong and so it's becoming difficult. I want to have it so if for whatever reason a movie can't save - it adds an error and moves to the next. After the JSON has been fully parsed I can then see which movies encountered errors. I've tried doing errors.add(:base, "Movie #{movie.title} can't be saved" .. and then in my movie/new.html.erb having a loop of the errors but @movie is undefined there.

So far to trigger my create action I have a button on my new.html.erb that sends a post request to trigger the create action and so parse the JSON.

```
<%= link_to "Get New Movies", movies_path, method: :post %>
```

Which parts am I doing wrong that is making it difficult. I want it so from my new movie page I can click a button and this triggers movie parsing - at the end of parsing if there are errors I can display them - else just redirect to the index page. I could do this if my controller just made a single object but the whole model method parsing json and creating multiple records is the thing that is throwing me off.

Comment: I think you may need `if @movie.save` rather than `if @movie` to trigger an attempt at saving that record to the database.

Comment: The @movie isn't saved - within the parse json method it maps the json to a block that parses it and saves each movie record to the databaase.

Comment: You make it sound like `Movie.parse_json` parses many movies, but it also seems like it only returns a single movie? Doesn't make sense. Maybe you should have a special view and action for this peculiar parsing process?